# Sorting two arrays by the order of one of the arrays [Swift 3.0 - Xcode 8]

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, sorting, structure

```
var ArrayToShowInTable = [String]()
```

I have two arrays:

```
let list = ["Carrot", "Apple", "Toothbrush", "Pear", "Oranges"]
let price = [3.50, 2.50, 1.50, 3.25, 4.25]
```

I want to order both these arrays by price (smallest to biggest),
So I get something like:

```
list = ["Toothbrush", "Apple", "Pear", "Carrot", "Oranges"]
price = [1.50, 2.50, 3.25, 3.50, 4.25]
```

So I can them join them

```
for i in 0...list.count-1{
let join = list[i] += "\(price[i])"
ArrayToShowInTable.append(join)
}
```

And then present it in a TableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (ArrayToShowInTable.count)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "TableCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = ArrayToShowInTable[indexPath.row] as? String
    return (cell)
```

Is there a way of doing this? 
maybe use a struct and print to table?

Please help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Dictionary` to match the `Products` and `Prices`. Handling in array is difficult to handle.

```
let product = ["Carrot" : 3.50, "Apple" : 2.50, "Toothbrush" : 1.50, "Pear" : 3.25, "Oranges" : 4.25]


var sortedItem = product.sorted { ( first : (key: String, value: Double), second:(key: String, value: Double)) -> Bool in
    return first.value < second.value
}

var productList = [String]()
var priceList =  [Double]()

for (key, value) in sortedItem  {
    productList.append(key)
    priceList.append(value)
}

print(productList)
print(priceList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create object:

```
class Product{
    var price : Double = 0.0
    var name: String =""
    init(price:Double, name:String) {
         self.price = price
         self.name = name
    }
}
```

Then you can declare your array:

```
var arrayToShowInTable = [Product]()
```

You can use only `arrayToShowInTable`

```
arrayToShowInTable = [Product(price:3.5, name:"Carrot"), Product(price:2.5 ,name: "Apple"), Product(price: 1.5,name: "Toothbrush"), Product(price: 3.25, name: "Pear"), Product(price: 4.25,name: "Oranges")]
```

Then, you can sort it like following:

```
arrayToShowInTable = arrayToShowInTable.sorted({$0.price < $1.price})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array of dictionaries  .

```
let list = ["Carrot" : 3.50, "Apple" : 2.50, "Toothbrush" : 1.50, "Pear" : 3.25 , "Oranges" : 4.25]
let sortedList = fruitsDict.sorted{ $0.value < $1.value }
```

Comment: Dictionaries cannot be sorted since they have no order

Comment: sorry it will be array of Dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary so the prices and the name will be in sync, and you will have to worry about sync their location after sorting.

Use sorted function to sort the dictionary and then use in table view function.

```
let pricesList = ["Carrot": 3.50, "Apple": 2.50, "Toothbrush": 1.50, "Pear": 3.25, "Oranges": 4.25]

var result = pricesList.sorted(by: {(a,b) in
    a.value as Double! < b.value as Double!

}) //or sorted{ $0.value < $1.value }
```

In TableView:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return result.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "TableCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(result[i].key) \(result[i].value)"
    return (cell)
```

If you have to use two arrays you can create dictionary from both of them.
and if you can't use dictionary, let me know.